# ¿como hacer un llamado desde angular hacia una api enviando el token?

Tags: angular, api, get

Estoy trabajando con angular al hacer un llamado get a la api debo enviar el token de autorización. El token lo he guardo en el localStorage porque así lo piden, para enviarlo en el get. He intentado de muchas formas, me aparece este error:"has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Este es la funcion que tengo en el servicio.

´´´

```
getheroe():Observable<any>{
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));
   let direccion = this.url;
   const headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer my-token',   'My-Custom-Header': 'foobar' }
   this.http.get<any>(this.url, {headers}).subscribe(data=>{
  return this
    })
  return this.http.get<any>(direccion);
  }
```

```
Gracias
```

Comment: CORS es una medida de seguridad de los servidores. Necesitas indicarle a tu servidor que la url `localhost` es una url válida puesto que por defecto solo la propia URL es válida, para evitar que te ataquen desde otros sitios.

Comment: la forma `..'Authorization':` `Bearer ${token}``.......>pero como no compartiste tu codigo para ver como manejas el token y ademas la mejor forma es usando interceptores https://programmerclick.com/article/64502145514/